# Datastore Callbacks and App Engine Modules in Java

Tags: google-app-engine

does anyone has tested google app engine modules (that are currently in preview)?

The documentation says that "Stateful services (such as Memcache, **Datastore**, and Task Queues) are shared by all the modules in an application", so I've tested if are also shared datastore callbacks across modules, but my test seems to show that if a module put something, the preput (or postput) event are fired only for the module that put the entity.

Is this the expected behaviour or maybe I missing something? this is the code:

MODULE1:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("kind", "id");
    Entity e;
    e = new Entity(key);
    ds.put(e);
    super.doPost(req, resp);
}
@PrePut(kinds = { "kind" })
void updateTimestamp(PutContext context) {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("ContatoreModulo1", "contatore");
    Entity e;
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        e = ds.get(key);
        counter = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e.getProperty("count")));
        counter++;
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e1) {
        e = new Entity(key);
    }
    e.setProperty("count", String.valueOf(counter));
    ds.put(e);
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

MODULE2:

```
@PrePut(kinds = { "kind" })
void updateTimestamp(PutContext context) {
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("ContatoreModulo2", "contatore");
    Entity e;
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        e = ds.get(key);
        counter = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e.getProperty("count")));
        counter++;
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e1) {
        e = new Entity(key);
    }
    e.setProperty("count", String.valueOf(counter));
    ds.put(e);
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Simply, in MODULE1 i put an entity with kind "kind", and then in both modules I try to catch the preput callback for this entity, but I see that only the preput declared in MODULE1 is called...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Modules are separate instances: different code is run, but the stateful services are the same. Basically, GAE starts separate server instances that run different modules code, but use the same datastore.

The code that you run is executed on one server instance and from within your program, you can only control program flow on that instance (except if you explicitly call another instance via Url fetch).

Also note that when you have a lot of traffic, GAE will start multiple server instances of one module to handle that traffic.

This has some consequences:

1. If you run some code on one instance, this will not magically invoke code on another instance, whether it's the same module or not. Your PrePut code is called only on the instance where you called put().
2. When there is a lot of traffic, multiple instances of module will run. Again, your PrePut code is called only on the instance where you called put(), not on all other instances.
3. If you use static variables to store some data, this data will be only visible on this particular server instance, not on other instances.
4. The only way to share data between instances are stateful services: if you want to have data shared between instances and between requests, then store it into datastore, memcache, etc..